# PHP best solution for multiprocess

Tags: php, bash, multiprocessing

I'm having a website with high demands for a certain task.
Let's say there are 100.000 requests / 2-3 hours to execute an bash script that takes 1-2 seconds to execute( optimizing images uploaded on the website ).

I need some advices. 
What's the best approach ?

First, i think at something like:

For every task, do something like this:

```
<?php
$somearg = escapeshellarg('blah');
exec("php file2.php $somearg > /dev/null &");
```

But i think creating 100.000 processes it.s not the best way.

It would be better to create a php script that runs continuously and checks
 for new tasks ?

Comment: Cron jobs are your friend

Comment: so, you say to make a cronjob every .. 30 min 1 hour to check if new tasks appeared and execute processes for them ?

Comment: _so, you say to make a cronjob every .. 30 min 1 hour.._ Yes, you might play with the time intervals depending on the load that you are expecting

Comment: and there is no problem if i exec( ) a process for every task ? problem like .. too many processes?

Comment: In conjunction with a cron, you should consider a Job queue. So, you can set the cron execution to run more often

Comment: _too many processes?_ I dont know how many processes your application will generate....you know it.. find it out ;)

Comment: lets say 100.000, but they are termianted after execution, is a lot for a normal server?

Comment: I dont know what your definition of a normal server is. You have to find it out. You could start a test before going live. I'm out..